# How to show a view each 5 rows in another view

Tags: views, theming

I'd like to create a complex view which combines several views.
I'm using Views Infinite Scroll

The view logic:

view A row-1

view A row-2

view A row-3

view A row-4

view B Block 1

view A row-5

view A row-6

view A row-7

view A row-8

view B Block 2

The difference between view B Block 1 and view B Block 2 is that Block 2 has offset from view B Block 1

Ok the adequate minimum is to insert view B Block 1 to each n row of the view A.

I tried to insert block in the view template but vainly.

Please help!

Comment: I don't believe this is possible, but would love to see someone prove me wrong. The only way I see it, is to break them into different views with offsets, but you won't be able to use infinite scroll.

Comment: Hey  No Sssweat, i'm already using different spitted views and as you mentioned it's not cool

Comment: Can you check this link of  OsTraining, where they have mentioned how to add other view as a field in the current view, check the last final image, you may get idea. [Link](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/views-field-view/)

Comment: codenext, if i use views_field_view the view will be embed to each row. Of course i can render view like this and then hide all embed view except nth-child(5) rows... But this is not very cool too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be done by overriding your View's template for the Style Output plugin (e.g. views-view-unformatted--yourview_machine_name.tpl.php). Then in that template outputting something like this:

```
<?php if (!empty($title)): ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $id => $row): ?>
  <div<?php if ($classes_array[$id]) { print ' class="' . $classes_array[$id] .'"';  } ?>>
    <?php print $row; ?>
    <?php
      // this tells the view to do something after every 4 rows
      if (($id % 4) == 0):
      print views_embed_view('view_machine_name', 'block_1');
      } ?>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If you wanted to alternate your secondary View's blocks - you could add some logic for that too.

Comment: this looks promising

Comment: Thank you. So some reason it didn't work then i tried this last time. I inserted view in template and it shows up! Finally. Well it breaks the view with views_infinite_scroll but it is progress

Comment: @Errand , Infinite Scroll must be doing some custom preprocessing of the View's rows - look into that module's code and see how it grabs rows for dynamic loading. Also, the above approach works perfectly with [Views Load More](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_load_more) pager plugin. If it is not mandatory for you to use Infinite scroll, I'd say Views Load More can be a very good alternative.